# pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers error

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to replace a string with a int in pandas but i'm getting this error,
does anyone know what i did wrong?

```
        print(self.df['verdeling'].str.split('/ ',expand=True))
        ramen = pd.DataFrame(self.df['verdeling'].str.split('/ ',expand=True))

        print(ramen)
        ramen = ramen.iloc[:,0].replace({'twee delen':2,
                                    'een deel':1,
                                    'drie delen':3,})
        # bijramen =self.df['verdeling'].str.split('/ ').get(1)
        bijramen = ramen.iloc[:,1].replace({'een bovenlicht':1,
                                        'twee bovenlichten':2,
                                        'een onderlicht':1,
                                        'teee onderlichte':2})
        self.df['ramen'] = ramen
        self.df['bijramen'] = bijramen
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 873, in __getitem__      
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1443, in _getitem_tuple  
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 700, in _has_valid_tuple 
    raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Comment: You set `ramen = ramen.iloc[:,0]` and afterwards you try to access `bijramen = ramen.iloc[:,1]`: This looks a bit odd.

Comment: thank you @Timus this was indeed the problem